# Corda with mockito_kotlin for unit test

Tags: corda

Hi I am trying to mock a Offchain/ API hit that is querying a offchain database / sepaarate external system. however i am facing problems when using mockito_kotlin to mock the response from the functions, it seems like the portion was not taken up during the starting of different nodes.

Is there any example or ways to perform this?

**Edited:**

I have a function `callExternalService()` which will return a string from offLedger service

```
class ExternalService {
  fun callExternalService() : String {
      // Call external service
      return externalResult
  }
}
```

I mocked the class using Mockito before the execution of flow as below:

```
val externalService = Mockito.mock(ExternalService::class.java)
Mockito.doReturn("Hello").`when`(externalService.callExternalService()).toString()
```

I have tried to call to the mocked `callExternalService()` during the flow and after the `FinalityFlow` to get some mock data. However when the unit test runs, the mocked class is not injected and the *"Hello"* is not returned from the class.

Hence, i was suspecting that the mock function is not taken into the nodes during the base start-nodes sequence, as it was still trying to hit an external service where I do not want to involve another external system for unit test purposes.

Comment: Can you post the code you have and isn't working, to get a sense of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Added Elaboration for the question* :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following service:

```
@CordaService
class ExternalService: SingletonSerializeAsToken() {
    fun callExternalService() : String {
        val externalResult = TODO("Call external service")
        return externalResult
    }
}
```

You'd need to pull the call to the service out into a separate function in your flow. Make this separate function and the flow class itself open, so that they can be overridden:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
open class RealFlow : FlowLogic<String>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): String {
        return queryService()
    }

    @Suspendable
    open fun queryService(): String {
        return serviceHub.cordaService(ExternalService::class.java).callExternalService()
    }
}
```

Now create a test subclass of the flow that overrides `queryService` to return dummy data instead of calling out to an API:

```
class TestFlow : RealFlow() {
    override fun queryService(): String {
        return "dummyData"
    }
}
```

You can now use `TestFlow` in flow tests to test the functionality of the main flow:

```
@Test
fun `example test`() {
    val flow = TestFlow()
    val future = node.services.startFlow(flow).resultFuture
    network.runNetwork()
    val externalResult = future.getOrThrow()
    assertEquals("dummyData", externalResult)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify which Corda services to be loaded when unit testing? I have a problem where the flow which uses the service is used as a sub flow. And I would have to create a TestFlow which calls TestSubFlow which uses mocked service with dummy data.

All usage of corda services is done by calling the serviceHub.cordaService method and I can't figure out a way to replace the service called in the cordaService method with a mocked one in my unit tests.