# How to mock an inlined InitiatingFlow return value during another flow

Tags: corda

I have `SomeBigFlow` that calls multiple subflows inside it i.e `ValidateFlowA`, `ValidateFlowB`. Assuming it is mandatory for A and B to be initiating flows not functions.

How do I mock a return value for `ValidateFlowA` when I run the `SomeBigFlow` in Junit?

I've seen some references to using `registerAnswer` to mock flows' return value [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/577033441adb590bb88f34f5fdac4f138a4d8fbf/core/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/ReceiveAllFlowTests.kt#L59). I am also curious why this function is only available for `InternalMockNetwork.MockNode` but not `MockNetwork.StartedMockNode` which is typically used during junit testing)

I thought I could replicate it by having `node[1].registerAnswer(ValidateFlowA.class, 20)`. But when I ran `node[1].startFlow(SomeBigFlow).resultFuture.getOrThrow()`, the `ValidateFlowA` is still using its default `call` implementation instead of returning the mocked 20 integer value. Maybe I'm using it wrong.

Any pointers on how to make this work or is there a solution to achieve mocking inlined subflows returned values? The only other way I can think of is have a rule of thumb that whenever calling an inlined subflow, put them in an `open fun` that can be overridden during mocknetwork testing - this makes inlined subflow tedious, hoping for a neater way.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you'd have to use a similar approach to the one outlined here: [Corda with mockito_kotlin for unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337338/corda-with-mockito-kotlin-for-unit-test).

In summary:

1. Make the `FlowLogic` class you are testing `open`, and move the call to the subflow into an `open` method
2. For testing, create a subclass of the `open` `FlowLogic` class where you override the `open` method to return a dummy result
3. Use this subclass in testing